How to detect when visionOS app is looked at? Are there dedicated visionOS specific lifecycle events?
In iOS we can use scenePhase to detect when the app is foregrounded and use that as an opportunity to refresh data.
It does not appear to work in visionOS for apps that remain open. I need a way of refreshing data and I am struggling to find the correct lifecycle event to initiate it.
.onChange(of: scenePhase) { _, newPhase in
    switch newPhase {
        case .active:
            // Would like to refresh data but this is only called when 
            // closing the app and reopening it. Not when looking at the app 
            // (or even interacting with the app) after looking at another app
        default: return
    }
}


You'll have to come up with another way to trigger your data refresh.
It's possible to have multiple apps open in the Shared Space, so there's no phase change when I interact with or look at a different app. Gaze direction is not shared with apps, so you won't be able to know when your app is looked at.
Apple Vision Pro
Privacy Overview points out (page 6):

Where you look is not shared with apps because the content we look at, and how
long we look at it, may reveal our thought process. visionOS processes eye
movements at the system level, and doesn’t share where you are looking, or your
eye input, with apps or websites before you engage with content. As a result,
apps and websites only know what content you select when you tap your fingers
together, not what you look at but don’t select.

You won't know what the user is looking at until they look at a control and tap it.
